# Search Youtube and return XML

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Is there a url I can use the search for 'Transformers movie' on YouTube, and return XML with a list of videos?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Transformers+movie. It's an atom feed to be exactly (but that's XML). More information about the API can be found at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#Searching_for_Videos

Comment: Just a suggestion: You could set the parameter `prettyprint=true` for XML response

Comment: @gopi1410 As far as I can see are they both XML responses. The only difference is that without the `prettyprint` parameter, all enters and indents will be removed to compress the data.
I would recommend the `prettyprint`parameter if you're reading it manually, but if it's parsed by some kind of program it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check this out:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Linkin+Park&prettyprint=true

P.S. You must have `prettyprint=true` for getting an XML response.

API details (many other useful options available): https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#Searching_for_Videos

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is :-)

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Transformers+movie&max-results=50&orderby=relevance&format=5&prettyprint=true&v=2

Here some more info

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol